# Getting Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused when running Minecraft.jar on TAILS linux

Tags: linux, java, tor, minecraft, tails

I am running Tails from an USB stick (because hard drive is broken) and when I try to run Minecraft I keep getting the same error. Should I specify any parameter when calling Java? How do I solve this?

Please, assume `(launcher.pack.lzma)` as `https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma` (Super User thinks I'm doing spam)

```
Bootstrap (v5)
Current time is May 17, 2015 3:17:57 PM
System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Linux'
System.getProperty('os.version') == '3.16.0-4-amd64'
System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'i386'
System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.7.0_79'
System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '32'

Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 2/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 3/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 4/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 5/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 6/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 7/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 8/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 9/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Downloading: (launcher.pack.lzma) (try 10/10)
Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
Unable to download remote file. Check your internet connection/proxy settings.
FATAL ERROR: net.minecraft.bootstrap.FatalBootstrapError: Unable to download while being forced
        at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.execute(Bootstrap.java:95)
        at net.minecraft.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:381)


Please fix the error and restart.
```

Answer (score -2):

Type this on Terminal **sudo update-ca-certificates -f** and enjoy...